# axis scaling with very small numbers

Tags: matlab

I have a code in which I need to plot two functions, where the x axis consists of very small numbers (a magnitude of 10^-6 on avarage).
This is the code:

```
Na = 10^18;
Nd = 10^15;
X_n = 9.941913007683443e-05;
X_p = 9.931981026656786e-08;
eps_0 = 8.85*10^-14;
eps_r = 11.8;
q = 1.6*10^-19;

x1 = -X_p:0.000000001:0;
x2 = 0:0.00000001:X_n;

v1 = (q*Na/eps_0*eps_r).*(x1.^2/2+X_p.*x1)+(X_p^2*q*Na)/(2*eps_0*eps_r);
v2 = (-q*Nd/eps_0*eps_r).*(x2.^2/2-X_n.*x2)+(X_p^2*q*Na)/(2*eps_0*eps_r);
figure (2)
plot(x1,v1,'r');
figure (1)
plot(x2,v2);

% plot(x1,v1,'r');
% hold on;
% plot(x2,v2);
```

Here, the two graphs are seperated so you can see how different they are. I want to plot those two functions in one graph. I tried, as you can see, with the hold on command, but because of the different magnitude of each function it's not working. I also tried using axis equal, axis auto, etc. commands and it didn't work as well.

What can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider using `subplot`?

I don't believe you can have both graphs in the same figure if you must use `x1` and `x2`. But you could try:

```
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x1,v1,'r');
title('title one')
xlabel('some values')
ylabel('some other values')
lg = legend('This curve represents...')
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x2,v2,'b');
title('title two')
xlabel('some values')
ylabel('some other values')
lg2 = legend('This curve represents...')
```

**Edit**

Try this one! I am giving you an example which you can modify.

```
x1 = 0:0.1:40;
y1 = 4.*cos(x1)./(x1+2);
x2 = 1:0.2:20;
y2 = x2.^2./x2.^3;
```

There you have two x-values and two y-values which are different, then use `line`:

```
line(x1,y1,'Color','r') % The first plot!
haxes1 = gca; % handle to axes
set(haxes1,'XColor','r','YColor','r') % sets the first x,y_axis of different color, this time will be red, but you can change this if you want
```

Then:

```
haxes1_pos = get(haxes1,'Position'); % store position of first axes
haxes2 = axes('Position',haxes1_pos,...
          'XAxisLocation','top',...
          'YAxisLocation','right',...
          'Color','none');
```

Use the code exactly as you are looking it. You can skip the `'YAxisLocation','right',...` if you want, Try the code and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you but it has to be in the same graph, subplot isn't helping, unfortunately.

Comment: @Eran I have made an edit to my answer. May be it will help you!

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this soon and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try scaling one or both until the difference between them isn't so dramatic. Otherwise, the smaller will always be virtually (and visually) zero.

Comment: You mean change x1 and x2? I've tried playing it with but with no results.

Comment: Yep, like... multiply (a copy of) the smaller until its range of values is no less than perhaps 1/10 the range of the larger - preferably it'd be adjusted until the two were in about the same range. Otherwise... imagine plotting (on paper) one huge range in the X axis versus a comparatively microscopic range in the Y axis. You'd get a visually flat line on paper.